# How to detect the change points in a signal?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a signal that I obtained by computing the pixel-based-sum of the difference between consecutive image frames in a video. Basically, I want to detect whenever there is a lack of continuity between two scenes. The signal structure seems to change between non continuous frames. However, I am not able to quantify such changes. For instance, in the image below, there is a change at 10450, 11000, 11800, 12,500, 13,500, 14000 etc. How can I detect these points automatically?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the changepoint package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/index.html

Comment: No. But, I will try now. Thanks :)

Comment: Reminds me of the video use case in this article: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-012-0300-z

Comment: Are you trying to detect scene changes in video?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to calculate the variance and the mean of your samples over a number of data points continuously and to compare the value of this mean and also the variance. 
By doing that, you will reduce the noise of your data and be able to see clearly a difference.
You can afterwards use a Hypothesis test to give a statistical proof of the modification.

Comment: The approach is inefficient for very long signals.